# Figure width problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, two-column, width

I have a problem in a figure which i draw, the figure doesn't fit in one column of two column paper as shown in the fig below, any help?
[image]

```
\begin{figure}{H}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  simple/.style={draw,text width=1.5cm,align=center,minimum size=1.5em},
  node distance=11mm
]
\node (xn) {$x[n]$};
\node[simple,right = of xn] (dft) {DFT};
\node[simple,right = of dft] (log) {log};
\node[simple,right = of log] (idf) {IDFT};
\node[,right = of idf] (cn) {$c[n]$};
\draw[dashed] ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=10pt]dft.north west) rectangle ([xshift=10pt,yshift=-10pt]idf.south east) ;
\draw[->] (xn) -- (dft);
\draw[->] (dft) -- node[auto] {$X[k]$} (log);
\draw[->] (log) -- node[auto] {$\hat{X}[k]$} (idf);
\draw[->] (idf) -- (cn);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Cepstrum representation.} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Reduce the widths and/or the node distance.

Comment: In case you can't reduce the figure's size sufficiently to make it fit inside the width of one column, you may want use the `figure*` environment in order to generate a "float" that spans both columns. The only restriction on positioning (at least for the LaTeX document classes I'm familiar with) is that the `figure*`s will be placed at the *top* of a page, across the two columns. The `[H]`, `[h]`, and `[b]` location specifiers will have no effect, so don't provide them.

Comment: Try to see if `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]...\end{tikzpicture}` works for you.

Comment: @Thanos Difficult to scale with positioning. Better idea it's to reduce node distance like Qrrbrbirlbel wrote. If you use `transform shape` then you change too much things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's difficult to give a correct answer because because you need to give us the requests used for your pictures.

What you want : same size for the nodes ? same size for the arrows? What size for the dashed rectangle ? where do you want to place $X[k]$ ?

If I want to scale a picture, I try to avoid positioning. I think it's more easy without it. Then If the scale is more important, it's impossible to place  $X[k]$ between (dft) and (log). I put $X[k]$  above these nodes. If you keep the normal size for the fonts it's impossible to use a coefficient < 0.6 to scale the picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,
    simple/.style={minimum width=8ex, minimum height=2em,draw}
]

\path   (0,0)     node         (xn)  {$x[n]$}
      ++(16ex,0)  node[simple] (dft) {DFT} 
      ++(16ex,0)  node[simple] (log) {log}
      ++(16ex,0)  node[simple] (idf) {IDFT}
      ++(16ex,0)  node         (cn)   {$c[n]$};

 \draw[->] (xn)  -- coordinate (m1) (dft);
 \draw[->] (dft) -- node[above=.9em] {$X[k]$} (log);
 \draw[->] (log) -- node[above=.9em] {$\hat{X}[k]$} (idf);
 \draw[->] (idf) -- coordinate (m2) (cn);
 \draw[dashed] ([yshift=-3em]m1) rectangle ([yshift=+3em]m2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Cepstrum representation.} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6,
    simple/.style={minimum width=8ex, minimum height=2em,draw}
]
\path   (0,0)     node         (xn)  {$x[n]$}
      ++(16ex,0)  node[simple] (dft) {DFT} 
      ++(16ex,0)  node[simple] (log) {log}
      ++(16ex,0)  node[simple] (idf) {IDFT}
      ++(16ex,0)  node      (cn)   {$c[n]$};

 \draw[->] (xn) -- coordinate (m1) (dft);
 \draw[->] (dft) -- node[above=.9em] {$X[k]$} (log);
 \draw[->] (log) -- node[above=.9em] {$\hat{X}[k]$} (idf);
 \draw[->] (idf) -- coordinate (m2) (cn);
 \draw[dashed] ([yshift=-5em]m1) rectangle ([yshift=+5em]m2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Cepstrum representation.} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]